# SqlException: Invalid object name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting started on a new project using EF core.
I have an existing database on MSSQL server and I run this command in order to include its structure for EF.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server={My Server};Database={My DB};Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

This has created the model classes for me, such as:

```
public partial class Cameras
{
    public int CameraId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and the following context class:

```
public partial class SetupToolContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Cameras> Cameras { get; set; }

    public SetupToolContext(DbContextOptions<SetupToolContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cameras>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CameraId)
                .HasName("PK_Cameras");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnType("varchar(500)");
        });
    }
}
```

I have 4 layers in my solution:

- BusinessLogic
- DAL
- Interfaces (for dependency injection)
- API (controllers)

Here is how the flow looks like in my code:

**Controller class**

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    ICameraRepository cameraRepository;

    public ValuesController(ICameraRepository cameraRepository)
    {
        this.cameraRepository = cameraRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Cameras> Get()
    {
        //ERROR: "Invalid object name 'Cameras'."
        return cameraRepository.List();
    }
}
```

**CameraRepository class**

```
public class CamerasRepository : GenericRepository<Cameras>, ICameraRepository
{
    private readonly SetupToolContext dbContext;

    public CamerasRepository(SetupToolContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

public interface ICameraRepository : IRepository<Cameras>
{ }
```

**GenericRepository class** (to try and follow the [Repository Pattern](http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/))

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly SetupToolContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(SetupToolContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> List()
    {
        return dbContext.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> List();
}
```

**And Startup class ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SetupToolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<ICameraRepository, CamerasRepository>();
}
```

The issue is that I'm getting an error: `"Invalid object name 'Cameras'."`

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]
What is wrong in this process?

Comment: What's the name of the table in the database? Is it `cameras`?

Comment: The name is "Cameras". It was automatically generated by the `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

Comment: The name Cameras was automatically generated by EF, but what about the table name? Just to confirm.. is it Cameras? Because that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Please don't put tags into the question title, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: The name of the table in the database is also "Cameras". I checked it again...

Comment: Maybe you are hitting some pluralization error/bug. Try renaming your model to `Camera`. Your naming conventions are already confusing enough (a method called `List()` which returns enumerable, `Cameras` when it represents **an entity**, etc) or add `entity.ToTable("Cameras")` to the EF Core Config method

Comment: I'll try it. Do you think it would be better to use the code first approach for this case? Maybe EF core works better with code first..?

Comment: Either way works, if configured correctly. EF Core has some default conventions (i.e. DbSet names determine table name since rc2, `<ClassName>Id` is primary key by convention etc.)

Comment: So, is EF generated the "Cameras" class for me, why do you think I need to change it to "Camera"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kind of embarrassing to say, but I will still post this answer in case anyone else will have the same error because of not noticing this "minor" detail.
I have 2 databases and it turns out I forgot to change the database name in the connection string to the correct one.
I changed it in the `Scaffold-DbContext` command and just forgot to also change it in the connection string...

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLServerConnection": "Server=localhost;Database={I had the wrong db name here};Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

So changing it the correct one solved it.

Comment: Don't feel too embarrassed. Found this answer and discovered I'd made the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

I had an entirely different problem, and it came with an entirely different solution.

As I was scaffolding, I was going between different databases during my development.

here is the command I used to scaffold from my local database

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --data-annotations "Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WebApp_DEV;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context-dir Data --output-dir Models --force --no-onconfiguring
```

It places the Context object into the "Data" folder, and the Components into the "Models" folder.

I got rid of the "OnConfiguring" so that I could create my own in a corresponding partial.

I created a static helper function on my Program class so that I didnt have to reference the context directly every time I wanted to access the database.

[image: Multiple Context Objects]

My helper method used the "WebApp_MainContext" class, and my partial worked fine.... But the classes added in Dev never worked.... Frustrating me for hours.....

I tried copying it over in my script, but it requires a manual class rename..

In retrospect, trying a simple file copy was pretty dumb...